# Can I preallocate a very big cell which will grow to an unknown size?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I have a function inside a for loop, this function takes an image and breaks it down into the number of components the input image had, it ranges from 2 to 7. Then saves these individually into cells, so if the input image had 7 components it will produce an `7*1` output cell.

The loop will then take the next image from the database, and do the same and concatenate that output with the previous cell.

In the end I am looking at a cell size of roughly 20,000+.

I know without pre allocation it will be a very slow process, but how can I initialise a cell without knowing its size?

Comment: I don't think you will have problem with `cell` (not a matrix), you could use `a = {};` before the loop.

Comment: Do you know the number of images you would be working with? Are you certain that the number of components in any image would not exceed 7? As Kamtal said, cell pre-allocation should be lightweight, so just start with `{}` and keep appending with `A{end} = data`.

Comment: Would it be an option to use different data structures? E.g. [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) grow very efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach #1

Assuming that you know the number of images that you would be working with, you can pre-allocate output for the maximum size, as you also know the maximum number of components, `7` you would have for any image.

Here's the nested loops part of the code that could be suggested to achieve the pre-allocation and storing results -

```
output_cell = cell(7,num_images)
for iter1 = 1:num_images
    for iter2 = 1:num_components
        output_cell{iter1,iter2} = result;
    end
end
```

As an example, let's assume you ran your codes for 3 images, so after code run you are left with something like this -

```
output_cell = 
    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]
    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [2x1 double]
    [6x1 double]    [6x1 double]    [6x1 double]
    [2x1 double]              []    [2x1 double]
    [4x1 double]              []    [4x1 double]
              []              []    [4x1 double]
              []              []    [2x1 double]
```

After that, you can remove the empty cells with this -

```
>> output_cell(cellfun('isempty',output_cell))=[]

output_cell = 
  Columns 1 through 8
    [4x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [6x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [6x1 double]
  Columns 9 through 15
    [4x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [6x1 double]    [2x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [2x1 double]
```

Thus, you would left with only the valid cells with all components info for all images in a 1D cell array, which is what you were looking to have as the final output.

---

### Approach #2

Here's a no pre-allocation technique that you can employ -

```
output_cell = {}; Initialize as an empty cell array
for iter1 = 1:num_images
    for iter2 = 1:num_components
        output_cell{end+1} = result;
    end
end
```

This would give you a 1D cell array just like in `approach #1`.

Comment: Please note that `num_components` might vary with each image i.e., it might depend on `iter1`, so take the codes as pseudo-codes/guiding methods.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate it in blocks and have a fixed/variable block step size.

Say, initially, your block step size (**M**) is 100. So before the first image, all cells will have a size of 100.

If during your iterations you find that a cell has insufficient space, allocate **M** more elements to only that cell and so on.

A second option would be to find out which components are likely to reoccur more frequently than others. If you find that one component is causing the cell size to grow very quickly, increase M for that particular component only and allocate more elements to that component's cell than the others.